# Pyspark collectAsMap() UDAF alternative - Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o62.__getstate__

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

I am trying to apply aggregated function to columns in pyspark. The context is I have only Spark 2.2 at hand and no option of using vectorized pandas_udf

```
sdt = spark.createDataFrame(zip([random.randint(1,100) for x in range(20)], [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(20)]), schema=['col1', 'col2'])
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|  19|  51|
|  95|  56|
|  11|  94|
|  80|  99|
|  20|  80|
|  38|  91|
|  18|  88|
|   4|  33|
+----+----+
```

In order to parallelize the columns, I convert it into rdd

```
sdt_col_rdd = sc.parallelize(sdt.columns)
```

Testing works fine with ordinary python functions, returning panda's dataframe

```
x = sdt_col_rdd.map(lambda col : (col, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))))
y = x.collectAsMap() #collect into dictionary with column names as key
print(y['col1']; print(y['col2']);
    A   B   C   D
0  14  55   4  57
1  36  84  53  51
    A   B   C   D
0  14  55   4  57
1  36  84  53  51
```

Switching into spark dataframe, here's also a sample function returning panda's df, but process Spark's df and use it's native aggregations, transformation, actions, etc. :

```
def myFunc(df, c):
    #other more processing, aggregation, transformation may be performed here
    res = df.agg((F.min(c)-1).alias("min_"+c), (F.max(c)+1).alias("max_"+c)).toPandas()
    res["col_name"] = c
    return res
```

Function works fine on its own

```
myFunc(sdt.select('col1'), 'col1')
    min_col1    max_col1    col_name
0   4   100 col1
```

Issues arise when I put that inside rdd map, similar to what has been done above

```
x= sdt_col_rdd.map(lambda col: (col,myFunc(sdt.select(col), col)))
y = x.collectAsMap()
```

Any idea how to achieve this kind of transformations/actions in Spark for columns in parallel, without *udaf* ? Collect_list would not be efficient because of huge dataset and without exploiting Spark's functions.

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 col_map = sdt_col_rdd.map(lambda col: (col,myFunc(sdt.select(col), col)))
>   ----> 2 y = col_map.collectAsMap()
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collectAsMap(self)    1555         4    1556         """
>   -> 1557         return dict(self.collect())    1558     1559     def keys(self):
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
>       794         """
>       795         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
>   --> 796             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
>       797         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
>       798
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _jrdd(self)    2440     2441         wrapped_func =
>   _wrap_function(self.ctx, self.func, self._prev_jrdd_deserializer,
>   -> 2442                                       self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)    2443         python_rdd =
>   self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD(self._prev_jrdd.rdd(), wrapped_func,    2444
>   self.preservesPartitioning)
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _wrap_function(sc, func, deserializer, serializer, profiler)
>   2373     assert serializer, "serializer should not be empty"    2374
>   command = (func, profiler, deserializer, serializer)
>   -> 2375     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)    2376     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes,
>   sc.pythonExec,    2377                                   sc.pythonVer,
>   broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)    2359     # the serialized
>   command will be compressed by broadcast    2360     ser =
>   CloudPickleSerializer()
>   -> 2361     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)    2362     if len(pickled_command) > (1 << 20):  # 1M    2363         # The
>   broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py
>   in dumps(self, obj)
>       462 
>       463     def dumps(self, obj):
>   --> 464         return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
>       465 
>       466
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py
>   in dumps(obj, protocol)
>       702 
>       703     cp = CloudPickler(file,protocol)
>   --> 704     cp.dump(obj)
>       705 
>       706     return file.getvalue()
>
> /data/2/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.603055/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py
>   in dump(self, obj)
>       160                 msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.**class**.**name**, emsg)
>       161             print_exec(sys.stderr)
>   --> 162             raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
>       163 
>       164     def save_memoryview(self, obj):
>
> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error
>   occurred while calling o62.**getstate**. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
>   Method **getstate**([]) does not exist    at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>     at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
>     at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)    at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: As I mentioned, row-based UDF would not work in this case. We need UDAF, which is not available in Spark 2.2 and I am looking for alternatives, without using _collect_list_ because 1/ That will lose the Spark distributed power on that single column; we are tuning down to plain own Python list 2/collect_list will have trouble with millions of records

Comment: Seems like you didn't catch this part of the accepted answer - "You are passing a pyspark dataframe, df_whitelist to a UDF, pyspark dataframes cannot be pickled. You are also doing computations on a dataframe inside a UDF which is not acceptable (not possible)."

Answer (score -1):

Seems you did not register your udf, import the udf function & register the udf as showed below, that should work.

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

myFunc=udf(myFunc,StringType())

Comment: As far as I understand, udf is for Spark dataframe, row-based. I am accessing as rdd, because it's column-based, and not data frame. Besides, udf is not for aggregate function I think. That would be UDAF which would have solved my problem; unfortunately I don;t have. Also, result is expected to be panda's dataframe. Would StringType() work ?